# Remove an object with the same value of an array inside an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, sorting

I have array like this:

```
[
    {givenName: "Name 1", phoneNumbers: [
        {label: "mobile", id: "5", number: "097 726 94 36"},
        {label: "other", id: "558", number: "0977269436"},
        {label: "other", id: "559", number: "0977269436"}
    ]},
    {givenName: "Name 2", phoneNumbers: [
        {label: "mobile", id: "5", number: "0968234838"},
        {label: "other", id: "558", number: "0966766555"},
        {label: "other", id: "559", number: "0966766555"}
    ]},
    {givenName: "Name 3", phoneNumbers: [
        {label: "other", id: "558", number: "0965777238"},
        {label: "other", id: "559", number: "0965777238"}
    ]},
]
```

Then I filter the `number` to get a `number` that is less than or equal to 10 digits.
Then returns an array with items that do not match a `number`.

I then iterate through each of the above items, then push it into an empty array to get each individual item.

And my final result array like so:

```
[
    {givenName: "Name 1", phoneNumbers: "0977269436"},
    {givenName: "Name 2", phoneNumbers: "0968234838"},
    {givenName: "Name 2", phoneNumbers: "0966766555"},
    {givenName: "Name 3", phoneNumbers: "0965777238"}
]
```

Bellow is my code, it works normally.

I just wanted to ask if there's a better way than my code.:

```js
const contacts = [
  {givenName: "Name 1", phoneNumbers: [
    {label: "mobile", id: "5", number: "097 726 94 36"},
    {label: "other", id: "558", number: "0977269436"},
    {label: "other", id: "559", number: "0977269436"}
  ]},
  {givenName: "Name 2", phoneNumbers: [
    {label: "mobile", id: "5", number: "0968234838"},
    {label: "other", id: "558", number: "0966766555"},
    {label: "other", id: "559", number: "0966766555"}
  ]},
  {givenName: "Name 3", phoneNumbers: [
    {label: "other", id: "558", number: "0965777238"},
    {label: "other", id: "559", number: "0965777238"}
  ]},
]

const listContactsLocal = [];
const contactFilter = contacts.map((item) => {
  const listPhone = item?.phoneNumbers.filter((phone, index) => {
    return (
      index === item?.phoneNumbers.findIndex((obj) => {
        if (phone.number.length > 11) {
          return;
        }
        return obj.number === phone.number;
      })
    );
  });

  return {
    givenName: item?.givenName,
    phoneNumbers: listPhone,
  };
});

contactFilter.map((item) => {
  return item?.phoneNumbers.map((phone) => {
    return listContactsLocal.push({
      givenName: item?.givenName,
      phoneNumbers: phone?.number,
    });
  });
});


console.log(listContactsLocal)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Sorry about my English.

Thank you. :))

Comment: So you always want to have one phone number? Even when there are no duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I just want to have one phone number. @Gh05d

Comment: This probably belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank for your information @pilchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this down to a `reduce()` call inside a `flatMap` to flatten the resulting nested arrays.

```js
const contacts = [{ givenName: "Name 1", phoneNumbers: [{ label: "mobile", id: "5", number: "097 726 94 36" }, { label: "other", id: "558", number: "0977269436" }, { label: "other", id: "559", number: "0977269436" }] }, { givenName: "Name 2", phoneNumbers: [{ label: "mobile", id: "5", number: "0968234838" }, { label: "other", id: "558", number: "0966766555" }, { label: "other", id: "559", number: "0966766555" }] }, { givenName: "Name 3", phoneNumbers: [{ label: "other", id: "558", number: "0965777238" }, { label: "other", id: "559", number: "0965777238" }] },];

const
  isFirstInstance = (number, index, arr) => arr.findIndex(o => o.number === number) === index,
  result = contacts.flatMap(({ givenName, phoneNumbers }) => (
    phoneNumbers.reduce((acc, { number }, i) => {
      if (number.length < 11 && isFirstInstance(number, i, phoneNumbers)) {
        acc.push({ givenName, phoneNumbers: number })
      }
      return acc;
    }, [])
  ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Set in javascript to have the unique number and add this logic bellow:

```
    let my_new_array = [].concat.apply([],contacts.map(obj => {
        let numberArray = [...new Set(obj.phoneNumbers.map(phoneobj => 
             phoneobj.number.replace(/\s+/g, '')))]
          return numberArray.map(number => ({
          givenName: obj.givenName,
          phoneNumbers: number
      }))
    }))
```

I test it in my IDE and this is the result

[image]

Comment: How about I want to split it into separate arrays?

Comment: Sorry i didn't flaten :) ... i edited my answer :D

Comment: Yeah, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is one reduce:

```
const res = contacts.reduce((acc, cV) => {
   acc.push({
    givenName: cV.givenName,
    phoneNumber: cV.phoneNumbers?.find(phone => phone.number.length <= 10)?.number,
  });
  return acc
}, []);
```

What happens is that you iterate through your array and search `phoneNumbers` - if it exists - for a valid number. I renamed the variable in the result to `phoneNumber` to better reflect what it is.

You can try it out in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/zYomwdr?editors=1011).

Comment: Should the `Name 2` value have two different numbers? You can check my console.log.

Comment: Ah, so you mean if there are several numbers then every not-duplicated number should have it's own entry?

Comment: Yah. I just want to have one phone number.